# JS, I want to make a button that opens the navigation over whole screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

*Edit: Everyone is disliking this post :(

So I want a button (I'll make a hamburger text) and when I click the button I want the whole page (the navigation element) to become (100% width and 100 height and I'll put flex in it) the navigation menu and when I click the button again the navigation element disappears.

What I want to know:

1. How do I do the CSS so that the navigation element opens over everything else? 
   position:absolute?

(After I know how to put the navigation element over everything else -
Maybe display: none on the navigation page and somehow put it over everything when I change display: visible with JS?)

2. Where can I find JS (because I don't know it yet) to edit CSS of the navigation element on click?

Something like this from W3, but I will probably need to change the diplay from none to visible and back again:

```
<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">
Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set your navigation into full screen, you should use `position:fixed` property of css. In order to properly hide and show the navbar you should toggle the class of the element instead of directly applying the display style. Take a look at below example to understand it better -

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let nav = document.getElementById('nav');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  //event listener toggling the active class
  if(nav.classList.contains('active')){
    nav.classList.remove('active'); //remove active class if already added
  } else {
    nav.classList.add('active'); //add active class if not added
  }  
});
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

nav{
  display: none; /*default in hidden state*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

nav.active{
  display: inline-block; /*visible if nav element contains active class, applied via JavaScript code*/
}

#btn{
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  Full screen content
</nav>

<button id="btn">toggle full screen element</button>

<p>Some static content</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add css position:absolute; and z-index=99 to your navigation element and toggle its display with onclick.